# Show all tasks in Home Page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want to show all tasks of all the subsites in my Home Page (admin) so when I open my "all task" list,I will see all the task under it .
Kindly Help

Comment: what version and edition of SharePoint on you on?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **content query web part** . It can filter items from all sites and subsites in a site collection and apply additional filter parameters.

---

*You can use the following link for reference*

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/15735